# High performance alternatives to STL?

Tags: c++, stl

What cache friendly high performance alternatives are there to the traditional STL.
They should be optimized for the caches of modern 64bit Intel/AMD CPU's.

I'm not looking for official standards based STL implementations necessarily it could be based on that or be an extended STL with high performance data structures.  Or simply a library that provides general data structures like list, map etc.

High concurrency and lock free data structures would be a bonus.

I'm interested in a link & a licence.

I've read about EASTL and have used Boost before.

What are game developers and the scientific community using to get the most out of the CPU's at the moment?  What is in the pipeline?

Comment: Well that is true. We are now able to use the GPU for more than just graphics now

Comment: Well, I wouldn't ask the scientific computing people, if I were you. At least not the ones that still use fortran, and claim that it's faster than C...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

+1 for EASTL.

Anything based on a C++11 compliant compiler will potentially perform a lot better because of move semantics.

This difference can already be made visible with the GNU libstdc++ implementation with `-std=c++0x`

For concurrency/lockfree containers I recommend:

- [libCds](http://libcds.sourceforge.net) by Max Khiszinsky
- TBB from Intel (no hands-on experience)

My **central piece of advice** would be this:

*Optimizing the standard library is mostly a factor of deciding how to use algorithms/containers correctly than looking for the 'perfect' implementation. STL being general purpose, there would never be a perfect implementation.*

Just watch your return values/out parameters closely (prefer to use output iterators, and use `transform`, `partial_sum`, `accumulate` into a container that had `reserve` or `resize` called on it appropriately; Define `swap` for your element types etc.)

Comment: +1: You can't have both "general purpose" and "perfect for a specific purpose"

Comment: Interesting what your say about move semantics in c++11. Is that implemented in visual studio 2011 ?

Comment: @MattH, Visual Studio 2010 supports move semantics and the Standard Library implementation takes advantage of it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the Standard Template Adaptive Parallel Library [STAPL](https://parasol.tamu.edu/stapl/), may well be one of the most important research collaborations at the moment.

Microsoft are investing significant effort into the [Asynchronous Agents Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492627.aspx), which has a number of well tested high performance containers for message passing.

Intel have their own offering, [Thread Building Blocks](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/) that contains a number of containers and algorithms for parallel processing.

Comment: For the record, I find this a very good addition; apart from TBB these are still unknown to me, the +1 was on me :)

Answer (score 1):

Boost Compute is definitely a runner up.

http://boostorg.github.io/compute/